# Classic Mechanics of a rigid Body- Kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

What what the most important things to consider in order to find the kinetic energy, for a lagrangian, of a moving body under some given constraints? 
The body rotates around an axis without slipering.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "some given constraints"?  As is the question is vague.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the questions I ask myself about a situation:

1. What is the frame of reference in which you want to calculate the kinetic energy?
2. What is the velocity of the center of mass?
3. Is there rotational motion about the center of mass?